# EWS - Get a user's peers (same manager)

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to do an exchange query to get a user's peers, as it is shown in Global Address List.
My first thought is to run a query that returns all users with the same manager.

```
FindItemType request = new FindItemType();
DistinguishedFolderIdType[] fid = { new DistinguishedFolderIdType { Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.contacts } };

request.ParentFolderIds = fid;
request.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow;

ItemResponseShapeType props = new ItemResponseShapeType();
props.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties;

request.ItemShape = props;

// insert restriction where "someone@somewhere.com" = contactsManager

FindItemResponseType response = _binding.FindItem(request);
```

Unfortunately this queries my contacts list, not the GAL.
How can I do this correctly?

I cannot query AD (app is intended to run off of internal network) and also I don't use the EWS Managed API for various other reasons.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to access the GAL using EWS for Exchange 2007 and above; [Taken From Here](http://vivekiyer.net/2010/07/17/querying-the-global-address-list-gal-via-exchange-web-services-ews/) See the link for some valid pointers. This code searches the GAL for a particular contact.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
    esb.Url = @"https://myserver/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
    esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                          "username",
                          @"password",
                          @"domain");

    // Create the ResolveNamesType and set
    // the unresolved entry.
    ResolveNamesType rnType = new ResolveNamesType();
    rnType.ReturnFullContactData = true;
    rnType.UnresolvedEntry = "test";

    // Resolve names.
    ResolveNamesResponseType resolveNamesResponse = esb.ResolveNames(rnType);
    ArrayOfResponseMessagesType responses = resolveNamesResponse.ResponseMessages;

    // Check the result.
    if (responses.Items.Length > 0 && responses.Items[0].ResponseClass != ResponseClassType.Error)
    {
        ResolveNamesResponseMessageType responseMessage = responses.Items[0] as ResolveNamesResponseMessageType;

        // Display the resolution information.
        ResolutionType[] resolutions =
        responseMessage.ResolutionSet.Resolution;

        foreach (ResolutionType resolution in resolutions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + resolution.Contact.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("EmailAddress: " + resolution.Mailbox.EmailAddress);

            if (resolution.Contact.PhoneNumbers != null)
            {
                foreach (PhoneNumberDictionaryEntryType phone in resolution.Contact.PhoneNumbers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(phone.Key.ToString() + " : " + phone.Value);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Office location:" + resolution.Contact.OfficeLocation);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get this to work. I was aware of this approach, but I do not how to pass in a "where manager = xyz" type filter. Is it possible?